# Creating a reference variable in two statements

Tags: c++, reference

```
int x;
int& foo = x;

// foo is now a reference to x so this sets x to 56
foo = 56;
```

How can I split the statement `int& foo = x;` into two statements?

By splitting, I mean using two statements such as in the below example:

```
int y;
int* ptr = &y;
```

I can split the `int* ptr = &y` into two statements declaring the pointer first.

```
int* ptr;
ptr = &y; //then assigning the pointer to point to y
```

How to do a similar thing to a reference?  I'm looking also for an explanation on why or why not?

Comment: Short answer: you can't.

Comment: It simple, you can't. A reference **must** reference something, you can't have a hanging reference.

Comment: and why would you want to? It dosen't makes sense to refer to nothing for a reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just can't. Consider the reference like a `const` pointer:

`int& foo = x` is the same as `int * const foo = &x`.

That's why you can't re-assign a reference, or declare a new one without a value.

Comment: Sorry I just started learning C++. so we can't split declaration of const pointer to 2 statements / leave hanging declaration of const pointer? is it true?

Comment: @mon No, that's what the keyword 'const' means: it is a constant value, that cannot ne changed once it gets a value.

Comment: Okay I got it. So a const pointer can not be reassigned, and reference also can't be reassigned. We can't leave hanging declaration of const pointer, and declaration of reference also can't be left hanging.

Comment: @mon Almost true: you actually can leave hanging declaration of `const` pointer ;) Mostly because a pointer can be equal to `NULL` (a reference can't)

Answer (score 5):

No, this can not be done, there are only a few cases where an intializer for a reference can be omitted, from the draft C++ standard section `8.5.3` *[dcl.init.ref]*:

> The initializer can be omitted for a reference only in a parameter
>   declaration (8.3.5), in the declaration of a function return type, in
>   the declaration of a class member within its class definition (9.2),
>   and where the extern specifier is explicitly used. [ Example:
>
> ```
> int& r1; // error: initializer missing
> extern int& r2; // OK
> ```
>
> —end example ]

As to why we find the following rationale for why references are not resettable from [The Design and Evolution of C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/dne.html):

> It is not possible to change what a reference refers to after
>   initialization. That is once a C++ reference is initialized it cannot
>   be made to refer to a different object later; it cannot be re-bound. I
>   had in the past been bitten by Algol68 references where `r1=r2` can
>   either assign through r1 to the object referred to or assign to a new
>   reference value to r1 (re-binding r1) depending on the type of r2. I
>   wanted to avoid such problems in C++.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't.
A possible workaround is to use `std::boost::optional<T&>` or simply `T*`

```
int x;
boost::optional<int&> foo; // or int* foo = nullptr;

foo = x; // foo = &x;
// foo is now a 'reference' to x

*foo = 56; // now, we have x == 56
```

Answer (score 1):

There is such a thing as an empty pointer, but there is not such a thing as an empty reference. A reference **has to** have something that it refers to. It **must be** initialized.

```
int& r; // error
```

This is one of the main differences between a pointer and a reference, and is one of the reasons to potentially prefer taking a reference argument (must be valid) over a pointer argument (can be null).

Answer (score 0):

You have no way to do this.
Reference should be constant so you may only initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

No, a reference must be initialised as it is declared to support the guarantee that there are no references that point into nowhere.